# How do I remove all the compiz installation I did with this command, but keep the basic?

Tags: compiz

I don’t want to remove all compiz. I only want to have a unity with Ubuntu 16.04.3 64-bit, as if I’ve installed a second ago.

I installed all compiz settings with all the repository (main, universe, restricted and the other), and did: `sudo apt install compiz*`.

Comment: Deleted my post until you specify what flavor of 16.04.3 you are using, i.e. Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, lubuntu, ect. I assumed Ubuntu in which case my post was correct.

Comment: I’m using Ubuntu with Unity

Comment: Then do what  I answered with.

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal run this, one complete command.

`sudo apt purge compiz-fusion-bcop compiz-mate compiz-plugins-extra \
compiz-plugins-main compiz-plugins-main-default compiz-plugins-main-dev \
compizconfig-backend-kconfig kdelibs5-data libattica0.4 libdlrestrictions1 \
libkdecore5 libkdeui5 libmate-desktop-2-17 libmatekbd-common libmatekbd4 \
libmatemixer-common libmatemixer0 libqt4-svg mate-desktop-common mate-settings-daemon \
mate-settings-daemon-common ubuntu-mate-wallpapers-common`

That would just leave compizconfig-settings-manager & compiz-plugins which are useful but not 'default installed', remove if desired

After this you could **Check** `sudo apt autoremove` to see if anything additional, I'd suggest answering n (no) if not 100% sure of any removals..

Comment: @geremi You should consider 'Accepting' this answer then...